# Specifying number of polygons while doing conversion of raster to polygon in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, shapefile, polygon

I have got a raster image which I have successfully converted to polygon. From the attribute table, I have got 73,410 polygons (objects). However, I just need 20 polygons for further analysis of my map.

Is it possible to specify the number of required polygons during conversion or are there ways 73,390 features can be switched off?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, you say you "just need 20 polygons", why not delete 73,390 polygons, that leaves you with "just 20 polygons"?

Comment: Oh! yes, that is exactly the problem I have. I dont know how to delete the other polygons. Sorry, if my request is elementary. Thanks

Comment: Select by attribute, e.g. ID > 20, then run delete feature tool. Experiment with a backed up dataset.

Comment: @Hornbydd, kindly elaborate on "ID > 20, then run delete feature tool". I got the few other steps but not the others. I am using version 10.8.2. Thank you a lot!